# Why does the risk-free rate implied by put-call parity vary with strike prices?

Tags: option-pricing, interest-rates, put-call-parity, implied

Suppose I do the following:

- buy one lot of some underlying stock currently trading at price $S$,
- write a call with strike price $K$, earning some premium $C$, and
- buy a put with the same strike $K$, costing some premium $P$.

At expiration,
I will sell my shares at the strike price $K$ no matter which option is in the money,
so I paid $S - C + P$ for a synthetic bond of sorts with principal $K$.
Ignoring dividends
the implied risk-free discount factor is $D := (S - C + P) / K$.

Given the above I would expect $D$ to be more or less independent of the strike $K$.
However, performing this calculation on various options expiring a year from now,
I get this interesting shape that I don't understand:
[image: SPY-implied discount rate]

As you can see, for near-the-money options things look fine.
As of today 2023-12-22, the one-year treasury bill trades around 4.8%
and SPY pays a dividend yield of 1.4% so the discount rate implied by
at-the-money options (dashed line) seems very reasonable.
However I do not understand what goes on to the right of the figure,
where the implied risk-free rate seemingly tends to zero.

For what it's worth I observe the same phenomenon with low-dividend and dividend-less stocks:

[image: AAPL-implied discount rate]
[image: META-implied discount rate]

What explains the behavior observed at higher strike prices?

Comment: [This post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/47101/58786) is discussing a related issue. Namely that in a real market the put/call parity for itm/otm calls/puts (or vice versa) does not need to hold strictly. Arbitrage is always just a theoretical possibility. If the liquidity is against you there is nothing you can do to exploit it.

Comment: If the objective is to see what (r-d) the market is assuming, the procedure should be: (1) from prices of puts and calls, find the forward price F, (2) From F, S and T find (r-d).

Comment: The main issue are borrow costs / fundings costs which you don't model.

Comment: Thank you to all of you who commented, I will try to think things through in the directions you proposed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because the options are American.  High strike puts are optimal to exercise early, hence the implied discount factor should be closer to 1 on the right hand side

Comment: @dm63 thanks! That makes a lot of sense and indeed it looks like the (European) SPX index options don't show the same phenomenon.

Comment: Ok I posted it as an answer

Comment: TBH I liked this question. Out of curiosity: Can you provide a chart of the implied discount factor across strikes for the European type option you mentioned ?

Comment: @Kermittfrog let me try and do that soon (for some reason the data provider I use doesn't let me download index options as easily)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because the options are American. High strike puts are optimal to exercise early, hence the implied discount factor should be closer to 1 on the right hand side.